# Vbulletin - 2 If statements with greater than or less than added in

Tags: conditional-statements, vbulletin

I've been browsing around for the past few hours trying to come up with a solution/search for a little bit of help and I've had no luck. I think it's time I come to the experts and ask for some more advice or help, this will be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve;

This will be located in the Users postbit and displays to all forum users

Takes the userid of the person
Checks if they have > or < of a certain conditinal and displays an image

All I've been able to achieve is displaying an image and I just can't figure out how to add these other factors in. (I know it shouldn't be post1)

```
<vb:if condition="is_member_of($post, 1)">
<img src="image here">
</vb:if>
```

Comment: I'll try and explain this further as my first post is very vague. I need it to get their userid and then check if they have > or < of the conditional I set and then display an image on their postbit.  I'm really stuck on this and cannot work out how to fit this all together

Comment: What is the conditional you are setting? `$post['userid']` should get the user id of the poster iirc.